# bash directory shortcuts

Tags: bash

When I type `cd ~foo`, I'd like bash to take me to some directory `foo` as a shortcut for typing the full directory path of `foo`. and I'd like to be able to `cp ~foo/bar.txt ~/bar.txt` to copy a file from the `/foo/` directory to the home directory... So basically, I want something that works exactly like `~/` does, but where I specify what the directory should be. [I'm sure I should jfgi, but I don't know what to fg]

Comment: [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) has built-in support for this.  It's called "[named directories](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html#l20)"

Comment: I was looking for some shell-bookmarking tool for too long, and finally I've ended up with my own (fuzzy-search-based) solution that I like much more that anything else I've seen before. Check this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209892/46011

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The way I used to do this is to create a directory that contains symlinks to the directories you want shortcuts do, and add that directory to your CDPATH. CDPATH controls where `cd` will search when you switch directories, so if that directory of symlinks is in your CDPATH you can `cd` to any of the symlinked directories instantly:

```
mkdir ~/symlinks
ln -s /usr/bin ~/symlinks/b
export CDPATH=~/symlinks
cd b   # Switches to /usr/bin
```

The downside of course is it won't work if there's a directory in your current directory named "b" -- that takes precedence over the CDPATH

---

I normally dislike answers that say "first you need to switch shells", but this *exact* feature exists in [ZSH](http://www.zsh.org/), if you're willing to use that instead; it's called **named directories**. You export a variable `foo`, and when you refer to `~foo` it resolves to the value of `$foo`. This is especially convenient because it works in commands besides `cd`:

```
echo hi > /tmp/test
export t=/tmp
cat ~t/test   # Outputs "hi"
```

Comment: In what ways does this ZSH feature differ from doing:
     echo hi> /tmp/test;export t=/tmp; cat $t/test
At least on my machine, this works just fine.  The only difference is the character you have to type.

Comment: referring the op to zsh is the right thing to do. i've not missed that feature once in 15 years. seems like the kind of thing some people get really obsessed about while others don't care. that's why there is more than one shell.

Comment: @Steven It's pretty similar, but ZSH knows it's a named directory in this case so it can treat it specially in prompt expansions and shell built-in commands

Comment: [I'd mostly be doing this using emacs M-x shell (since that's when I use the terminal), I guess that rules out ZSH solutions]...

Comment: @Seamus Not at all, `M-x shell` just spawns your default shell inside an emacs buffer; you interact with it just like if it were in a terminal window. `M-x eshell`, on the other hand, is a shell written entirely in emacs

Comment: This works nicely, but how do I make the change permanent? If I close, and then restart the shell, it seems to forget the shortcut I made... (This might be because I haven't properly set it to be the default shell)

Comment: @Seamus Exports are temporary and go away when the shell ends; you want to put the `export` commands in a file that gets auto-loaded when your shell begins, like `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Added it to my .zshrc and that worked.

Comment: There's no need to export the var. exporting it is for telling subprocesses about the value of the variable, which is not needed as it is zsh which expands the directory alias.

Comment: This solution is nice and works fine, but if I do `cd foo` the shell (bash) says I am exactly in `~/.symlinks/foo` and not in (e.g.) `/var/www/foobar/bar/f/o/o/foo`... Some way how to make `cd symlink` follow the symlink to the end directory?

Comment: @shadyyx Use `cd -P foo`.

Comment: "The downside of course is it won't work if there's a directory in your current directory named "b" -- that takes precedence over the CDPATH" ... You could use `CDPATH=":~/symlinks"` instead. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456866/how-can-i-suppress-printing-the-full-path-to-subdirectories-when-using-cdpath

Answer (score 12):

You could write a wrapper function for `cd` and call it "cd" (ultimately the function will call `builtin cd` - using the `builtin` keyword). You could use a prefix character that Bash won't expand on the command line before your function sees it and that's unlikely to appear as the initial character in your directory names, perhaps ":". You would want to make it more robust, but here's a simple outline:

```
# format: [semicolon] shortcut colon destination [semicolon] ...
export CDDATA='foo:/path/to/foo;bar:/path/to/bar;baz:/path/to/baz'

cd () {
    local dest=$1
    if [[ $dest == :* ]]
    then
        [[ $CDDATA =~ (^|;)${dest:1}:([^;]*)(;|$) ]]
        dest=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    fi
    if [[ -z $dest ]]
    then
        cd
    else
        builtin cd "$dest"
    fi
}

cd :bar    # pwd is now /path/to/bar
```

Comment: This is a really good idea

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion - made my really simple solution on top of it: http://aaverin.github.io/unix/macox/2014/05/26/bash-named-folders/

Answer (score 7):

with bash:

`~foo` is reserved for the home directory of the user foo. I would not recommend creating users just for that convenience.

You can make your life easier (or harder) when *changing directories* by setting the `CDPATH` environment variable (look it up in `bash(1)`).

Apart from that, the only way to think of would be to set environment variables for those directories you want to abbreviate.

```
$ FOODIR=/var/lib/misc
$ cp ~/bar.txt $FOODIR
```

Answer (score 3):

Bash variables can be used to create a bookmarking system. Variables will work with any command and bash will tab complete the variable name. In newer versions of bash, if a / is appended to the variable name, the path the variable contains can be tab completed as well.

```
mydir=/home/chris/dir
ls $my         # Tab completion works on variable name.
ls $mydir/     # Tab completion is equivalent to that with ls /home/chris/dir/
               # (doesn't work in older versions of bash).
```

For persistence, variable declarations can be kept in a file that is sourced from .bashrc.  Since this file is a bash script, it can contain declarations that reference other variables, such as `aur="${HOME}/AUR"`, or that only run on certain hosts `if [[ $HOSTNAME == foo ]]; then bar=baz; fi`, which is useful if you reuse config files across multiple hosts and users.

The following bash function (to be added to .bashrc, or sourced from it) allows bookmarks to be added to and removed from the bookmarks file.  It is fairly new and not guaranteed to be free of bugs.

```
bookmark_file=~/.bookmarks
source "$bookmark_file"

bm() {
usage='Usage:
bm add <name> <path>           Create a bookmark for path.
bm add <name>                  Create a bookmark for the current directory.
bm update                      Source the bookmark file.
bm remove <name>               Remove a bookmark'              

case $1 in
    add)
        local path
        if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]; then
            path=.
        elif [[ $# -eq 3 ]]; then
            if [[ -e $3 ]]; then
                path="$3"
            else
                echo "bm: ${3}: No such file or directory."
                return 1
            fi               
        else
            echo "$usage"
            return 1
        fi

        if declare | grep "^${2}=" > /dev/null; then
            echo "bm: The name $2 is in use."
            return 1
        fi
        path=$(readlink -f "$path")
        echo ${2}=\""$path"\" >> "$bookmark_file"
        eval ${2}=\""$path"\"
        return 0
        ;;
    update)
        if [[ $# -eq 1 ]]; then
            source "$bookmark_file"
            return 0
        fi
        ;;
    remove)
        if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]; then
            unset $2
            local contents=$(grep -v "^${2}=" "$bookmark_file")
            echo "$contents" > "${bookmark_file}.tmp"
            rm -f "$bookmark_file"
            mv "${bookmark_file}.tmp" "$bookmark_file"
            return 0
        fi
        ;;
esac

echo "$usage"
return 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An way would be creating an alias for cd which replaces `~c` to the wanted path. Or just use zsh ;)

Comment: Yes, I thought about doing that, like alias ~c="cd /daten/cvs/plugin_root" but that only helps with cd, while named directories can be used with every command.

Answer (score 0):

For changing directories, you could use wcd: [Wherever Change Directory](http://www.xs4all.nl/~waterlan/)

With that, it'll be like `wcd plugin_root`.

Comment: I wanted something that works with commands other than `cd` as well...

Answer (score 0):

I have the below function which will create alias on the fly,

```
s () {
    if [[ "x$1" != "x" ]]
    then
        alias $1="cd $PWD;pwd"
        echo "alias $1=\"cd $PWD;pwd\""
    else
        echo "Usage: s[s] <directory bookmark name>"
        return 1
    fi
}
```

When I want to bookmark a directory, I just type `s dirName`. This creates a alias like `alias dirName="cd /my/current/directory/;pwd"`. so I can come back to this directory by just typing `dirName`. I have a version which saves it into bash_aliases as well. This works in any shell.