# Directory shortcuts in emacs buffer

Tags: zsh, emacs

So I asked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1469/bash-directory-shortcuts) about directory shortcuts in a shell. The idea is I'd like to be able to open a file in `/home/Documents/foo`, say, by typing <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> `~foo/file`.

So, is there a way to emulate zsh's "named directories" in the emacs buffer?

Incidentally, the shortcut definitions I want to use are already in my .zshrc, if there's a solution that reads them directly, that gets bonus points.

Comment: Perhaps this isn't a unix SE question and I should try my luck on SU?

Comment: this question isn't unix-specific (even down to the zsh part: there's a zsh port for Windows, or at least for Cygwin), so it should be on SU. But, well, it's here now, so I answered it here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Emacs component that's responsible for expanding `~` in file names is `expand-file-name`. Unfortunately, it's written in C, and deep inside its bowels is code that assumes that what comes after `~` is a user name. Fortunately, Emacs has a generic way of adding a wrapper around functions, so you can do what you want if you don't mind repeating some of the logic in the built-in function.

Here's some completely untested code that should get you going. Look up “Advising Emacs Lisp Functions” in the Emacs Lisp manual for more information; the basic idea is that `defadvice` adds some code to run before the actual code of `expand-file-name`. Please signal the mistakes I've inevitably made in comments (whether you know how to fix them or not).

```
(defvar expand-file-name-custom-tilde-alist
  '(("foo" . "/home/Documents/foo")))

(defadvice expand-file-name (before expand-file-name-custom-tilde
                             (name &optional default-directory)
                             activate compile)
  "User-defined expansions for ~NAME in file names."
  (save-match-data
    (when (string-match "\\`\\(\\(.*/\\)?~\\([^:/]+\\)\\)/" name)
      (let ((replacement (assoc (match-string 3 name) expand-file-name-custom-tilde-alist)))
        (when replacement
          (setq name (replace-match (cdr replacement) t t name 1)))))))
```

I'll leave parsing the shortcuts in `.zshrc` to fill `expand-file-name-custom-tilde-alist` (or whatever technique you choose to keep the aliases in synch) as an exercise.

Comment: My exercise solution: `(defun my/add-to-tilde-alist (hash)
  (let* ((tilde:dir (split-string hash "="))
         (tilde (car tilde:dir))
         (dir (cadr tilde:dir)))
    (push (cons tilde dir) expand-file-name-custom-tilde-alist)))

(mapc #'my/add-to-tilde-alist
      (split-string (with-output-to-string
                      (call-process "zsh" nil standard-output nil "-ic" "hash -d"))
                    "\n" t))`

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `$foo` instead of `~foo` in the minibuffer. Emacs will treat `foo` as the name of an environment variable and use its value.

Comment: What a killer hidden feature! 
(remark: export the variable for them to be available)