# How to mimic zsh named directories with bash

Tags: bash, zsh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bash directory shortcuts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1469/bash-directory-shortcuts)

zsh has the concept of named directories, so you can say in ~/.zshrc

```
c=/home/fschmitt/svn/plugin_root
: ~c
```

and later use this short cut in the shell like this

```
cd ~c/release
```

How to best emulate this with bash? I can of course say

```
export c=/home/fschmitt/svn/plugin_root
```

and then

```
cd $c/release
```

however firstly, the $ is complicated to input on German keyboard layout and secondly, I fear binding a variable with just a single letter name might give problems with unwanted variable expansion.