# How to create a bashrc/zshrc symlink?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh

I reinstall my OS a lot, and I've learned to start backing up configs in iCloud Drive folder

The command I generally run (after searching google for the nth time):

`ln -s "/Users/myName/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs" ~/icloud`

Currently, this `.zshrc` has a lot of `alias` commands eg

```
alias sublime="/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
```

---

I don't know how to add a global symlink / shortcut / token to this file

How can I persist the fact that `~/icloud` or `$icloud` or `ICLOUD` should always refer to that path?

Comment: You could set a variable `icloud="/Users/myName/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs"`, then refer to it as `$icloud`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit more research, it looks like I'm in luck given that I use zshell

[bash directory shortcuts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1469/bash-directory-shortcuts)

Apparently you can export any variable eg `export icloud="/Users/james/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs"` and refer to it via `~icloud`